# Getting this error: "Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid." visual studio

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to make a app for cafe. It has a simple interface coffee names with labels and quantity with numericupdown, receipt textbox and receipt button. I coded receipt button to show coffee name and quantity in receipt textbox like this:

```
If (espresso.Value > 0) Then receipt.AppendText("Espresso" + vbTab + vbTab + espresso.Value.ToString + Environment.NewLine)
```

that works fine but i want to add the price next to quantity of the coffee so i added these lines :

```
    Dim espressoprice As Double
    espressoprice = 3

    Dim espressoquantity As Double = Convert.ToDouble(espresso.Value)
    Dim espressototal As Double
    espressototal = (espressoprice * espressoquantity)
```

(espresso.value is numericupdown value)

and changed the first codeline like this:

```
If (espresso.Value > 0) Then receipt.AppendText("Espresso" + vbTab + vbTab + espresso.Value.ToString + vbTab + espressototal + Environment.NewLine)
```

but i keep getting this error:

> "Espresso    2    " "Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid."

What am i doing wrong please help.

Comment: In the `AppendText` function, should you not use `expressototal.ToString`? I do not think that this is related to the error you get, though.

Comment: i removed it and run the program again but i keep getting the same error. As you said it is not related to the error i get. Sadly. @robertbaron

Comment: On what line are you getting the error?

Comment: If (espresso.Value > 0) Then receipt.AppendText("Espresso" + vbTab + vbTab + espresso.Value.ToString + vbTab + espressototal + Environment.NewLine) in this line when i add + espressototal to it. @robertbaron

Comment: The only line that could generate that error message, is the line where there is the `Convert.ToDouble()`. Could you post more code that I would be able to try in Visual Studio?

Comment: interface is like this : http://prntscr.com/nzqi7a (Fiş means receipt it is in turkish i translated and posted it on here to make it easier to understand) and only code i have in button is : ` receipt.Clear()
        receipt.AppendText(vbTab + vbTab + "Cafe" + Environment.NewLine) ` and the same ones i mentioned in post.

Comment: Just to be sure, when you add `expressototal`, you add `expressototal.ToString`, right? Adding just `expressototal` without the `ToString` would cause an error.

Comment: Oh damn that .ToString made me lose my hours. Thank you it is fixed now :)

Comment: You are welcome! Same things happens to me all the times!

Comment: How can i tag your comment as answer im new to this site so i dont know how to do it.

Comment: Let me post my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper solution to this problem is to use the correct operator.  You are trying to perform string concatenation but you are using the addition operator.  This:

```
"Espresso" + vbTab + vbTab + espresso.Value.ToString + vbTab + espressototal + Environment.NewLine
```

is actually performing multiple additions.  Addition maps to concatenation for two `Strings` but for numbers, addition is mathematical, NOT textual.  In order to add a `String` and a numeric value, the system has to implicitly convert one of them to the other type.  You are obviously assuming that the number will be converted to a `String` but it's actually the opposite that is happening, i.e. the system is trying to convert a `String` to a number and it is failing.  This is why you should not rely on implicit conversions.  If you used the concatenation operator, as you should when performing concatenation, then there's only one way it can go:

```
"Espresso" & vbTab & vbTab & espresso.Value.ToString & vbTab & espressototal & Environment.NewLine
```

Notice that, in this case, you don't have to explicitly convert the number to a `String` because the concatenation operator is defined for `Strings` and numeric values.  Concatenation is a `String` operation so you know for a fact that everything that can be treated as a `String`, will be.

That said, there are better options anyway, e.g.

```
receipt.AppendText(String.Concat("Espresso", vbTab, vbTab, espresso.Value, vbTab, espressototal, Environment.NewLine)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your line where you added `expressototal` you need to convert its value to a string in order to add it to other strings, that is, `expressototal.ToString`.